# default_url not working with CarrierWave (Rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

I would like to display a default image, if the user doesn't upload an image. Here is my picture_uploader.rb and I uploaded default.png to /images/fallback. But I can't get it to work. Any tips, what could I try next?

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150]
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800511/carrierwave-default-image-doesnt-display

Answer (score 2):

According to your `default_url`, the name of your image should be `thumb_default.png`:

```
[2] pry(main)> version_name = 'thumb'
=> "thumb"
[3] pry(main)> [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
=> "thumb_default.png"
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the name to thumb_default.png, but it didn't work. I also tried with asset pipeline:     ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
and put the file to => "/assets/fallback/thumb_default.png" But that didn't work either. I don't understand where Rails gets the version_name?

Comment: Take a look to your servers log or use the web inspector to identify the name (and path) of the image that it's trying to find.